# Leaflet - Unwanted movement on clicking markers

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, leaflet

I am trying to make a map and markers with pop ups on clicking markers. I am using leaflet plugin for this. Everything is working fine, except, when i click on any marker, the map will move to some point, instead of focusing on the pop up of the marker. But if i alter the size of the browser (like restore down or open the console), then onward it will work fine. I have a function to get the HTML for the popup. Here is my code

```
      var cloudmadeUrl = 'https://server/tiles/test_format5_set4/tiles_{z}_{y}x{x}.png',marker,
        cloudmadeAttribution = '', latlng,
        cloudmade = new L.TileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {maxZoom: 4, attribution: cloudmadeAttribution});
        latlng = new L.LatLng(0, 0);
        var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
            options: {
                iconSize:     [25, 41],   // size of the icon
                shadowSize: [50, 64],   // size of the shadow 
                iconAnchor: [22, 94],   // / point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                shadowAnchor: [4, 62],    // the same for the shadow
                popupAnchor: [-3, -76]   // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            }
        });
        var completedIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '../styles/images/marker-icon green.png'});
        var startedIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '../styles/images/marker-icon red.png'});
        var createdIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '../styles/images/marker-icon yellow.png'});
    map = new L.Map('table_map', {center : latlng, zoom : 1, layers : [cloudmade]});
    ticket_layer.clearLayers();
    map.removeLayer(ticket_layer);
   for (var m in  SOURCE_ARRAY) {
                (function (n) {
                    if (SOURCE_ARRAY.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
                        createHtmlForPopUp(n, function (data) {

                            if (SOURCE_ARRAY[n].state.state === "created") {
                                marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(SOURCE_ARRAY[n].location.x, SOURCE_ARRAY[n].location.y), {icon: createdIcon});       
                            }
                            else if (SOURCE_ARRAY[n].state.state === "started") {
                                marker = new L.Marker([SOURCE_ARRAY[n].location.x, SOURCE_ARRAY[n].location.y], {icon: startedIcon});
                            }
                            else {
                                marker = new L.Marker([SOURCE_ARRAY[n].location.x, SOURCE_ARRAY[n].location.y], {icon: completedIcon});
                            }
                            marker.bindPopup(data); // calling a function with callback
                            ticket_layer.addLayer(marker);
                        });
                    }
                })(m);  
            } // for loop ends here

        map.addLayer(ticket_layer);
```

Comment: can you create a http://jsfiddle.net for the same

Comment: I tried but it is not working in fiddle. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hPkG8/) the one i tried, but it is giving error from Leaflet Object itself

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put the `autoPan` option to false?

[Docs.](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup)